# Case in Oracle WHERE clause

Tags: oracle

Following oracle query complies and works fine:

```
SELECT
    Employee.EmployeeId,
    Employee.EmployeeName,
    Employee.Description,
    Employee.IsFrozen 
FROM
    employee, employeerole, roledef
WHERE
    employee.employeeid = employeerole.employeeid 
    AND employeerole.roleid = roledef.roleid
    AND rolename IN (
                    CASE
                        WHEN (1 < 2)  THEN ('Owner Role')
                        WHEN (2 < 1)  THEN ('Eval Owner Role')
                    END);
```

Now in my case I would like to add in second when ie (2 < 1) two rolename('Owner Role' and 'Eval Owner Role'). 
Kindly suggest how will the above query change.

Thanks in advance.

-Justin Samuel

Comment: `2 < 1` is always false. What are you tryinig to do?

Comment: I know...just compiling the query. Or else lets reverse the when case. I just meant compiling....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why use a `CASE`?  Why not simply

```
AND (   ( (1 < 2) and rolename IN ('Owner Role', 'Eval Owner Role') )
     OR ( (2 < 1) and rolename IN ('Eval Owner Role') ) )
```

I am assuming that you don't actually have predicates that are hard-coded to evaluate to TRUE (1 < 2) or FALSE (2 < 1) and that those are actually bind variables in your actual code.

If you really want to use a `CASE` statement, you could code

```
AND( CASE WHEN (1 < 2) and rolename IN ('Owner Role', 'Eval Owner Role')
          THEN 1
          WHEN (2 < 1) and rolename IN ('Eval Owner Role') 
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END) = 1
```

but that is going to be much more difficult for the optimizer to deal with and much less clear for the developer that has to maintain it.

Comment: However as "ypercube" suggested I was looking for something using CASE statement. But could not solve the issue using CASE. But this definitely is another way to achieve the same! :)

Comment: @Justin - I updated the answer with an example that uses a `CASE` statement.  But as I mention, it's generally not a good idea to code it that way.